# Automatically select most expensive shipping rate

Tags: 8, commerce

In my Drupal 8 Commerce site I have two main product types that each have their own flat rate shipping cost. When both products are combined in the cart, Commerce will let the user pick the method.

Instead, I want the most expensive of the two shipping methods to be automatically used.

In Drupal 7 Commerce this could be done with Rules, but the Drupal 8 version has built in conditions. None of those seem to be able to work with multiple shipping rates.